# Do I need heteroscedasticity consistent Standard Errors in LMER when applying Heckman's two stage procedure?

Tags: lme4-nlme, heteroscedasticity, mixed-model

When including an Inverse Mill's ratio to account for selection in a mixed model using LMER in R (following Heckman's [1979] two-stage procedure), do I still need to estimate robust SEs or does the mixed model result in heteroscedasticity consistent SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am inclined to say you are having heteroskedastically consistent SE within clusters by design (ie. the assumptions you are doing when using `lmer`). That is because if you assumed otherwise you would have a saturated model.

In a saturated model you would practically assume separate error terms $\epsilon$ (some for cluster specific variance and one for a "sample-wide" error) and you would face unidentifiability:
$y = X\beta + Z\gamma + \epsilon_{cluster_1} + \cdots + \epsilon_{cluster_i} + \epsilon_{whole sample}$ (not cool)

Assuming no "sample-wide" error is not feasible using the current `lmer` implementation. `lmer`'s fitting procedure does assume you are able to work with the relative precision matrix $\Omega$ ([Bates and DebRoy 2003](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~bates/reports/MixedComp.pdf) offer a more detailed analysis of the matter.)

(I am not 100% sure about my interpretation of your question, so I am open to discussion on the matter.)